# Wine - How to make MilkShape 3D work?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I can install MilkShape 3D normally on Wine (4.21), but the program does not start.

Is there any solution/Workaround?

Thanks! **=D**

Comment: While I believe this is technically on topic (presuming your Wine is in Ubuntu), I've had poor/no help with Wine problems here.  Wine's own support isn't great, either.  You might get more useful assistance from the MilkShape 3D community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this version works we recommend creating a wineprefix for the installation.

Once Milk Shape 3D is installed, then install "vcrun6" using "winetricks".

MODEL

```
WINEPREFIX=<PATH_TO_WINEPREFIX> winetricks -q vcrun6
```

EXAMPLE

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/user_name/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/ms3d winetricks -q vcrun6
```

**NOTE:** If there are problems with the approach above you can try the following...

Copy both Dll's below to the 3D Milk Shape folder (where "ms3d.exe" is):

- "msvcirt.dll"

ARCH/VERSION: 32bit/6.0.8168.0
DOWNLOAD: https://www.dll-files.com/msvcirt.dll.html

- "MFC42.dll"

ARCH/VERSION: 32bit/6.0.400
DOWNLOAD: https://www.dlldump.com/download-dll-files_new.php/dllfiles/M/mfc42.dll/6.0.400/download.html

Done! **=D**

[Refs.: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14679 , https://portingteam.com/topic/4019-req-milkshape-3d-184/#entry37942 ]

---

**EXTRA:**

**How to register the application**

MilkShape 3D has an unusual problem with its registration process. **It accepts registry keys even if it is invalid**. There are several sites reporting a certain procedure where we have to wait a few minutes with the application open to validate the registration key. **This is a lie!** Insert the key ( "Help" > "About..." > "Register" ) close and open the application. If it doesn't work, the key is wrong.

[**Ref.:** https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14679 ]